# buffer overflow 64 bit issue

Tags: buffer-overflow, exploit-development

I have a problem when trying to overwrite the EIP (basic 64 bit buffer overflow) with an address 0x0000000000400546 which is a function that is located in the same program .. the EIP is at 88 bytes .. so my code in gdb will be :

gdb> r `python -c 'print "A"*88 + "\x46\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"'`

I finally get the address modified to : 0x00007fff00400546

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff00400546 in ?? ()

[image]

Why it is modified with the 7fff in the middle? And how to point to this specific address?

Comment: Please do not post things like instructions or code with an image, instead, use the inline code formatting feature.

Comment: Are you sure you need 88 bytes to control rip register ?

Comment: Please post in the comment section and not as an answer! Also I asked because how did you figure you can control rip with 88 bytes, did you make to successfully overwrite it using another hex value apart from `0x0000000000400546` ?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the of the vulnerable code I'm going to  guess that the vulnerable function uses a C based string operation like strcpy() which terminates on null byte. Hence your string stops writing after `\x46\x05\x40\x00` as it encounters a null byte. This results in a partial overwrite and the `0x00007fff` portion of the `0x00007fff00400546` address is whatever value was already on the stack.